# Доступ к БД SSMS с мобилки и с десктопа

Tags: c#, .net, ip, webapi

Всем привет. Нужна единая БД в MSSQL, с которой будет работать приложение WPF и мобилка на Xamarin. Причем мобилка должна работать с БД вне зависимости от того, к какой сети подключен телефон. Идея - WEB API. Могу ли я юзать ПК, как сервер и подключаться к БД удалённо с телефона, будучи не в одной сети?

Были попытки по поводу API, но не могу настроить всё так, чтобы мобилка могла достучаться до сервера SSMS через API. Причем проблема не в API(Postman корректно отправляет post и get). На строке с попыткой подрубиться к API выкидывает ошибку  `System.Net.WebException: 'Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)'`. Я так понимаю, что нужен частный IP, чтобы мобилка могла видеть API, но как это сделать, я не знаю.

Прошу помощи, куда мне грузануть API, чтобы с мобилки(при том, что мобилка может быть подключена и к мобильному интернету, и к wifi) можно было подключиться и достучаться до него? На веб-хостинг не вариант, хотя, проверяла, работает, но десктоп будет слишком медленно работать

url на данный момент: `const string Url = "http://192.168.0.106:45457/api/workTasks";`

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, можно ли с мобилки с любой точки на планете иметь доступ к десктопу, который стоит непонятно где и сеть которого настроена непонятно как, но зато который имеет доступ к какому то уже готовому серверу БД (который тоже непонятно где) и чтобы проскировать этот доступ на мобилку вы хотите написать веб сервер и встроить его в десктопное приложение. Я верно понял вопрос?

Comment: Ну, с любой точки планеты мне не надо. Нужно в пределах 100км +-. Да, может , вопрос звучит смешно, но мне нужно это как-то реализовать. web api уже написан. Неужели это нереально сделать?...